# TreeSet vs Collections.sort() java

Tags: java, collections

Let's say I had two options to add Items in a collection and have them sorted

Option 1: Iterate over all items and add the item to the TreeSet while iterating

Option 2: Iterate over all the items and add the item to a List, and after all items have been added use the Collections.sort() method.

Which option out of the two would have a faster runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would choose Option 2.

Time complexity of Collections.sort() is O(n*log(n)) (adding elements is O(n) but in the end O(n)+O(nlog(n))=O(nlog(n))), while TreeSet.Add has complexity of O(log n) resulting in O(n*log n) when adding all the items. So the complexity looks the same. The best way is to profile your actual code, the difference in both solutions is the constant factor which is not shown in Big O, and which I am preety sure is quite high in case of TreeSet.